# Firebase facebook authentication is not working properly for me

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I used Firebase UI for developing fb authentication in my app. Everything works smooth but when i try to login from other accounts it keeps on scrolling and gets to previous state as if nothing happened. Fb login only works with my account, the same account from which i login to developer.facebook.com and used credentials. So is there any option to enable fb login to all my users?. Here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Obtain the FirebaseAnalytics instance.
        mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if(mAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null)
        {
            Log.d("AUTH",mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
            //user already signed in
        }else {
            startActivityForResult(
                    AuthUI.getInstance()
                            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                            .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(
                                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
                                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build()))
                            .build(),
                    RC_SIGN_IN);
        }
        findViewById(R.id.log_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==RC_SIGN_IN){
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                //user logged in
                Log.d("AUTH",mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
            }
            else {
                //user not authenticated
                Log.d("AUTH","NOT AUTHENTICATED");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId()==R.id.log_out_button)
        {
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .signOut(this)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            Log.d("AUTH","USER LOGGED OUT");
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled the FB login in firebase console? What about setting up app ID for Firebase UI? And add FacebookLogin dependencies? You make sure everything done?  

Any traces of error?

Comment: Yes i did that. No error there. as i said fb login working for my account but not for others.

Comment: Have you set your app to “public”, and have you gotten it reviewed already (if applicable) …? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

Comment: Switch for dev mode/public is in the app dashboard, and regarding review … are you kidding me? I just linked to the documentation for that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok i got the answer. After that cambridge analytica you cannot use fb login publically unless your app is live on play store. You can still test the login functionality in developer mode. Thats why only i am able to login not others. For others to use you have to add them as tester in developer.facebook.com . Also make sure to updated privacy policy url first if your app is live and wants to add such functionality.